# Detect mouse and keyboard events on TravisCI

Tags: node.js, automation, travis-ci

I've been working on a native Node.js module called RobotJS that allows the user to automate the mouse and keyboard. I've been trying to find a way to automate testing for keyboard and mouse events. For example, I need to be able to confirm that RobotJS is sending the correct keycodes, like "a" and "!". And I need to be able to detect mouse clicks.

I got this working locally using the terminal, here is the code to detect mouse clicks:

https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs/blob/keyboard-tests/test/detectMouse.js

But it doesn't work on TravisCI. I imagine because they don't open an actual terminal window, even though I start xvfb and can detect mouse movement.

I considered writing a new application using Electron to open a window to detect the events, but I'd rather not if I could get my current tests to work.

Thoughts? Here's my current .travis.yml:

https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs/blob/master/.travis.yml

And here's the projects GitHub:

https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs